# How to represent tic tac toe table in Latex?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

Hi all I need numbers from 1.... 8 as below in a table.

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5 
6 7 8
```

Comment: But how do I get the lines in between them?

Comment: what is wrong with tabular?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The probably simplest way with tabular: use `|` for vertical lines and `\hline` for horizontal lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\      \hline
  4 & 5 & 6 \\      \hline
  7 & 8 & 9
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table]

For more complex drawings, I would use [TikZ](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz). The [TikZ example gallery](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/) provides many code examples for a start.