# Beamer: Noughts and crosses

Tags: tables, beamer, macros, columns

Is there a better way to build up a game of noughts and crosses in LaTeX? I currently have the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A game of noughts and crosses}

    Here is a game of noughts and crosses. On the left we have the game, and on the right the commentary.\\

    \begin{columns}

        \begin{column}{0.1\textwidth}

            \vspace{1.75cm}

            \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                & & \\      \hline
                & & \\      \hline
                & &
            \end{tabular}
        \end{column} \pause

        \begin{column}{0.70\textwidth}

            \begin{itemize}
                \item crosses goes first, makes optimal move. A good player will never lose from this start.
            \end{itemize}

        \end{column}

    \end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This splits the slide in two where I have the game on one side, and the commentary on the other. I want to be able to play the game by adding Os and Xs in the grid, slide by slide, whilst simultaneously adding commentary. Clearly the first move is:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
                & & \\      \hline
                & X & \\      \hline
                & &
\end{tabular}
```

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do this? How do I get the game to fill up slide by slide (i.e. X plays on slide 1, O plays on slide 2, add commentary, X plays on slide 3, etc.).

Comment: You need to look at overlay specifications in the manual. E.g. `\onslide<2->{X}` or whatever.

Comment: See [Creating Tic-Tac-Toe boards with LaTeX/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139782/5764)

Comment: Related: [How to represent tic tac toe table in Latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70742/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there is going to be a lot of repeated code (for the different games, in this instance), then I write a macro to simplify my latex file - and to make it easier to change things later, if needed.

**(I)** The first thought that came to mind was to write a macro that takes as "input":

- a comma separated list of the positions of the X's
- a comma separated list of the positions of the O's
- the commentary

The X and O positions I would encode as 1,2,...,9 reading from left to right, and top to bottom, in the grid. For example, `\NoughtsCrosses{5,6}{9}{Third move}` would produce

[image]

**(II)** A second way of doing this is to assume that the moves alternate as X,O,X,... and just give a comma separated list of moves together with the commentary. For example, `\NoughtsCrossesII{5,9,6,4}{Fourth move}` would produce

[image]

As cfr says in the comments to the question, you probably want to enclose these commands inside something like `\only<5>{\NoughtsCrossesII{5,9,6,4}{Fourth move}}` in order to reveal one move at a time.  I do this in the MWE below.

**(III)** Taking the last remark into account, and going a little OTT, a smarter macro would simply take a list of the moves and commentary and then construct all of the slides for the game in the frame. All of the macros so far use tikz and the tikz`\foreach` command allows for multiple looping variables separated by a slash, so the easiest way to implement this is to use the following syntax:

```
  \NoughtsCrossesGame{%
     5/First move,
     9/Second move,
     6/Third move,
     4/Fouth move
  }
```

The output is the "same" as above except that the "game" appears over 4 slides. The macro `\NoughtsCrossesGame` takes an optional argument, which behaves similar to the optional argument to the`\pause` command. That is, it acts as an "offset" controlling when the moves in the game start to appear in the slides for the given frame.

Here is code giving the definitions of the three macros above, completed to a MWE to show how to use them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Helper macro for placing a node at "position" 1,2,...,9 into the grid
% \PlaceMarker[optional node styling]<position><X or O>
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\PlaceMarker{ O{}mm }{%
   \ifnum#2>0
       \def\markercol{#1}
       \def\PlaceMakerNumber{#2}
    \else
       \def\markercol{red}
       \def\PlaceMakerNumber{\numexpr-#2}
    \fi
   \ifcase\PlaceMakerNumber%
      \or\node[\markercol] at (1,3) {#3}; % 1 = (3,1)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (2,3) {#3}; % 2 = (3,2)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (3,3) {#3}; % 3 = (3,3)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (1,2) {#3}; % 4 = (2,1)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (2,2) {#3}; % 5 = (2,2)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (3,2) {#3}; % 6 = (2,3)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (1,1) {#3}; % 7 = (1,1)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (2,1) {#3}; % 8 = (1,2)
      \or\node[\markercol] at (3,1) {#3}; % 9 = (1,3)
   \fi
}

% Creates a noughts and cross game with commentary
%\NoughtsCrosses{x-positions}{y-positions}{Commentary}
\newcommand\NoughtsCrosses[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5} {
         \draw[ultra thick](\x,0.5)--+(0,3);
         \draw[ultra thick](0.5,\x)--+(3,0);
     }
     \foreach \x in {#1} {\PlaceMarker{\x}{X}}
     \foreach \y in {#2} {\PlaceMarker{\y}{O}}
     \node[text width=40mm,text ragged, anchor=west] at (5,3) {#3};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Creates a noughts and cross game with commentary
%\NoughtsCrossesII{move positions}{Commentary}
% Moves alternate as X,O,...
\newcommand\NoughtsCrossesII[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5} {
         \draw[ultra thick](\x,0.5)--+(0,3);
         \draw[ultra thick](0.5,\x)--+(3,0);
     }
     \foreach \move [count=\m] in {#1} {
         \ifodd\m \PlaceMarker{\move}{X}
         \else\PlaceMarker{\move}{O}
         \fi
     }
     \node[text width=40mm,text ragged, anchor=west] at (5,3) {#2};% add comment
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Creates a noughts and cross game with commentary
%\NoughtsCrossesII{move positions}{Commentary}
% Moves alternate as X,O,...
\makeatletter
\newcommand\NoughtsCrossesGame[2][0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \foreach \x in {1.5,2.5} {
         \draw[ultra thick](\x,0.5)--+(0,3);
         \draw[ultra thick](0.5,\x)--+(3,0);
     }
     % count length of game
     \foreach \move/\com [count=\lmove] in {#2} {}
     \def\endgame{\the\numexpr\lmove+#1\relax}
     \def\Endgame{\the\numexpr\endgame+1\relax}
     \foreach \move/\com [count=\m,
                          evaluate=\m as \mm using int(\m+#1),
                          evaluate=\move as \mov using int(abs(-\move))] in {#2} {
         \ifodd\m\def\Marker{X}
         \else\def\Marker{O}
         \fi
         \def\mmm{\the\numexpr\mm+1\relax}
         \only<\mm>{\PlaceMarker[blue]{\mov}{\Marker}}
         \ifnum\move<0
            \only<\mmm-\endgame>{\PlaceMarker{\mov}{\Marker}}
            \only<\Endgame->{\PlaceMarker[blue]{\mov}{\Marker}}
         \else
            \only<\mmm->{\PlaceMarker{\mov}{\Marker}}
         \fi
         \only<\mm>{
           \node[text width=40mm,text ragged, anchor=west] at (5,3){\com};
         }
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{A game of noughts and crosses}
  Here is a game of noughts and crosses. On the left we have the
  game, and on the right the commentary.

  \medskip

  \only<2>{\NoughtsCrosses{5}{}{First move}}
  \only<3>{\NoughtsCrosses{5}{9}{Second move}}
  \only<4>{\NoughtsCrosses{5,6}{9}{Third move}}
  \only<5>{\NoughtsCrossesII{5,9,6,4}{Fourth move}}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Another game of noughts and crosses}
  Here is a game of noughts and crosses. On the left we have the
  game, and on the right the commentary.

  \pause Here is a clever game
  \medskip

  \NoughtsCrossesGame[1]{% offset start of game because of \pause above
    -5/First move,
     6/Middle square,
     7/Forcing,
     3/Forced block,
    -9/Forced block leading to a pincer!,
     8/Forced defence!,
    -1/Wins!
  }

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A few comments:

- All of the macros use [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to draw the games as this gives better control over the placement of the X/O markers and in drawing the grid
- The `\PlaceMarker` macro is a "helper function" for placing a marker at the specified position. This uses `\ifcase` to translate the position indices `1,2,...,9` into `(x,y)` coordinates.
- The macros use `\foreach` to loop over the comma separated list of marker positions. The second macro uses, in addition, `\ifodd` to determine whether to place an X or an O.
- The "commentary" is placed inside a tikz node as ragged left text of width 40mm. You might need to fine tune the placement of the (x,y)-coordinates and the width of the text.
- As requested in the comments I have improved the macros to allow easy highlighting of some of the moves. Giving a "negative position" index now colours the corresponding `X` or `O`. For example, `\NoughtsCrosses{-5,-6}{9}{Third move}` will make the two `X`s red.
- More amusingly, the `\NoughtsCrossesGame` macro now colours each move and then puts the final "winning" streak in blue at the end of the game - the winning streak must again be highlighted using negative position indices. In both cases the colouring is done by an enhancement to `\PlaceMarker`, although the automatic colouring for `\NoughtsCrosses` is more involved.

For completeness, here is an animated version of the last slide produced by the `\NoughtsCrossesGame` example:

[image]

Except for the frame made by beamer, this collection of slides is essentially the output of the command:

```
\NoughtsCrossesGame[1]{% offset start of game because of \pause above
  -5/First move,
   6/Middle square,
   7/Forcing,
   3/Forced block,
  -9/Forced block leading to a pincer!,
   8/Forced defence!,
  -1/Wins!
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. I have used this macro and created the game in my beamer document. One final question: is there a way to highlight all the noughts when you get three in a row?

Comment: @serveoverice I am not sure which of variant of the macro you are using. I assume that you want the Xs or Os to be highlighted only when there are three in a row? Doing this in the `\NoughtsCrossesGame` would be tricky, but Making another variant were user-specified Xs or Os were highlighted for a "single" slide would be straightforward.  How should the entries be highlighted? In red/blue/? Perhaps the @ast move should always be highlighted and a different highlighting/co;our be used at the end for three in a row.I don't have time to add this now but I'll see what I can do tonight.

Comment: I would like it just for the final slide (so a single slide). Highlighted in standard \alert red would suffice. I tried using \alert but I couldn't get it to work. I am using the \NoughtsCrosses macro. Whenever you can mate would be great. Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, did you think of a way to add colour into the game? I just need the final move to be highlighted as three in a row. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I figured out how to make the Os alert red using the following additional argument: \foreach \z in {#3} {\PlaceMarker{\z}{\alert{O}}}

Comment: @serveoverice Glad you figured out a way to do this. I haven't had time yet but I was planning to extend the macros above so that `-n` would put an alerted X or O in position `n`. Happy to do this if you're interested.

Comment: That sounds great. I'm completely new to macros so anything you can add that will help me learn would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @serveoverice I have "improved" the macros to allow colours.  See the last two dot points. I am surprised that you are not using the `\NoughtsCrossesGame` macro as it does "everything" for you. I have added an animated gif to show what it does.