# Creating Tic-Tac-Toe boards with LaTeX/TikZ without tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am currently writing my thesis and need to include figures of tic-tac-toe/noughts and crosses games.
Up until now I created my figures using PowerPoint (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKuqT.png), and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQvb3.png)).

I looked up similar questions and found the following ones:

1. [Beamer: Noughts and crosses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350471/beamer-noughts-and-crosses?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [How to represent tic tac toe table in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70742/how-to-represent-tic-tac-toe-table-in-latex)

However they either use a table to represent the game or macros to place an X or O character on a board. Since I also need dashed symbols (see image [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Om1.png)) to represent optimal moves I can not use their approach.So the individual slots of the board are either blank, contain their index or a symbol.
Furthermore I would like to place either a single line of text beneath the diagram or multiple lines to its right.

Could anybody point me to other questions or resources that I could use to create the figure below?

game of tic-tac-toe with zero-based index and text underneath
[image: game of tic-tac-toe with zero-based index and text underneath]

game of tic-tac-toe with empty slots and text on the right
[image: game of tic-tac-toe with empty slots and text on the right]

game of tic-tac-toe optimal moves highlighted by dashed symbol

[image: game of tic-tac-toe optimal moves highlighted by dashed symbol]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### EDIT

I thought it would be more interesting to just throw a *matrix* of what you wanted into the cells and get the result, so here is an improved version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\tictactoe}[1]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=2pt]
        \def\r{3mm}
            \tikzset{
                    circ/.pic={\draw circle (\r);},
                    cross/.pic={\draw (-\r,-\r) -- (\r,\r) (-\r,\r) -- (\r,-\r);},
                    opt/.pic={\draw[opacity=0.2] (-\r,-\r) -- (\r,\r) (-\r,\r) -- (\r,-\r);}
                    }
            
            % The grid
            \foreach \i in {1,2} \draw (\i,0) -- (\i,3) (0,\i) -- (3,\i);
            
            % Numbering the cells
            \setcounter{num}{0}
            \foreach \y in {0,...,2}
                \foreach \x in {0,...,2}
                    {
                    \coordinate (\thenum) at (\x+0.5,2-\y+0.5);
                    %\node[opacity=0.5] at (\thenum) {\sffamily\thenum}; % Uncomment to see numbers in the cells
                    \addtocounter{num}{1}
                    }
                    
                    
        \def\X{X} \def\x{x} \def\O{O} \def\n{n}
        
        \foreach \l [count = \i from 0] in {#1}
            {
            \if\l\X \path (\i) pic{cross};
            \else
                \if\l\O \path (\i) pic{circ};
                \else
                    \if\l\x \path (\i) pic{opt};
                    \else
                        \if\l\n \node[opacity=0.5] at (\i) {\sffamily\i};
                        \fi
                    \fi
                \fi
            \fi
            }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    

\begin{document}
    
    \tictactoe{O,x,n,
               x,X,x,
               n,x,O}
    
    \vspace*{1cm}
           
    \tictactoe{ ,O,X,
               O,X, ,
               X, ,O}           
                    
\end{document}
```

[image: TicTacToe]

[image: another one]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is easily understandable and greatly customizable too!
I posted a [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634724/220502) to create a game tree

Comment: This is really cool!