# How to write O, X symbols?

Tags: symbols

How to write O, X symbols properly?

I have tried \bigcircle, \texttimes commands, but their sizes are so different.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please show an image how the result should look like.

Comment: Do you want to [recreate a tic-tac-toe game](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/634666/47927)?

Comment: What do you not like about `O, X, $O$, and $X$`?

Answer (score 2):

With `\times` match perfectly in size `\ocircle`, not `\bigcirc`, and you have also `\otimes` that is almost the same that overlap both symbols (except that the thickness of × is adjusted to be the same that of the circle).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\makebox[1.5em]{
\makebox[0pt]{$\times$}%
\makebox[0pt]{$\ocircle$}} 
$\otimes$ 
$\times$ 
$\ocircle$ 
\end{document}
```